# How to disable SSLv3 protocol in Apache ActiveMQ?

Tags: security, ssl, activemq-classic

I want to disable SSLv3 protocol in Apache ActiveMQ.

Can not find relevant information here:
http://activemq.apache.org/ssl-transport-reference.html

The link above only shows how to configure CipherSuites

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an enabledProtocols option you can use on the transport connector. You can't exclude, but you can choose valid protocols.

```
transport.enabledProtocols=<comma separated list of SSL/TLS protocols>
```

So, a TLS only "default" transport connector should look like this:

```
<transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61618?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2&amp;maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

Comment: Will this disable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 as well? ["Remember, everything less than TLS 1.2 with an AEAD mode is cryptographically broken."](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/10/14/poodle.html)

Comment: yes, this will enable only TLS v1. To enable TLS v1.1 you should configure `transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.1`

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to enable multiple TLS versions.

Comment: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2} then changed to socket.enabledProtocols=<protocolValue> it accepted.