# How to disable SSL3 for activemq https transport?

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic

I am trying to disable SSL3 for activemq https transport. (activemq-5.11)

I tried the transport.enabledProtocols option as suggested in [How to disable SSLv3 protocol in Apache ActiveMQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436565/how-to-disable-sslv3-protocol-in-apache-activemq)

transport.enabledProtocols is working for ssl:// transport but not for https:// transport. 
I do not see a handshake failure when i try to connect with openssl using -ssl3 option.

Thanks

Comment: someone answer this please...

Answer (score 0):

Jetty front's the HTTP aspect of activemq, and uses a spring connector for the config. This lets you add the `excludeProtocols` property with `SSLv3` as the value:

```
<bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
    <property name="port" value="8162" />
    <property name="keystore" value="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="excludeProtocols" value="SSL,SSLv2,SSLv3" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be on .Net 4.5+ and in your code before calling the service add below:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol=SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

There is an article here:
http://passionatecoder.ca/Posts/Details/47